# WordPress Shortcode / Only works in classic editor, gutenberg error / invalid json response

Tags: shortcode, javascript, json

I'm trying to allow authors to add TV charts in the articles. For this reason, I added the following shortcode:

```
function cikkek_shortcode($atts) {
$option = shortcode_atts(
    array(
        'url'     => '',
        'options' => '',
    
    ),
    $atts
);
?>  

    
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://s3.tradingview.com/tv.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var tradingview_embed_options = {};
tradingview_embed_options.width = '640';
tradingview_embed_options.height = '400';
tradingview_embed_options.chart = '<?php echo $option['options']; ?>';
new TradingView.chart(tradingview_embed_options);
</script>
<p><a href="<?php echo $option['url']; ?>">
<?php
}
add_shortcode( 'cikkekembed', 'cikkek_shortcode' );
```

I created an article and input the following as a test:

```
[cikkekembed url='https://www.tradingview.com/chart/PLTR/MRrFdJON-PLTR-diamond-hands/ options='MRrFdJON']
```

1 -> Boom, I got an invalid json response. I read a bit online and if I understood correctly, a shortcode inside a HTML tag is not possible?

2 -> Anyway, I tried taking some stuff out, but it didn't help, so I thought it might not be related to that

3 -> Installed classic editor, the shortcode works like a charm.

How can I get this working in Gutenberg?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

A shortcode should only ever `return` content, never `echo` it. The bits between the `?>` and `<?php` tags -- the `<script>` tags and the rest -- are effectively being `echo`ed to the browser, which means that the JSON content that Gutenberg expects is no longer valid.

From the [`add_shortcode()` docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_shortcode/):

> Note that the function called by the shortcode should *never* produce an output of any kind. Shortcode functions should *return* the text that is to be used to replace the shortcode. Producing the output directly will lead to unexpected results.

Also, instead of sending those `<script>` tags directly, you should enqueue them. See [`wp_enqueue_script()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/). Since you are passing data from PHP to at least one of your scripts, see also [`wp_localize_script()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_localize_script/).